# 555 timer capacitor charging order

Tags: 555, capacitor-charging

I have a question about the standard 555 circuit below. I understand to some degree the "insides" of the timer. In particular, I understand the role the comparators play and I am fairly certain I am able to follow the logic as the voltage going into pins 2 and 6 increases.

My main difficulty comes in understanding why the same voltage (+5V say) charging the capacitor isn't also going into pins 2 and 6. As it has been explained to me "the capacitor voltage is what is fed into the comparators," however this seems counterintuitive as in my mind there should be a Vcc voltage (+5V) fed into the comparators as well as the capacitor, and it seems to me that this voltage would drive the logic.

The explanation I've been able to convince myself of is that "Vcc is providing only as much voltage to the capacitor as the capacitor currently has" -- this however seems to not be in line with the explanation as there seems to be an implication that the capacitor is what is flowing into pins 2 and 6 and not the voltage straight from Vcc. If this is the correct explanation, then it appears I am missing some key intuition for the workings of voltage in such circuits and would greatly appreciate an explanation/reference.

My understanding of electronics is very basic, so I expect I'm missing something easy, or more fundamental.

[image]

Comment: Is it bad that I recognize the graphical style of that schematic and that it reduces my trust into the circuit even being sensible?

Comment: Voltage doesn't flow. Current flows! And it does flow into 2 and 6, but only a very little amount: these are high-impedance input pins.

Comment: I edited out references to "voltage flowing" and updated to a hand drawn (but empirically tested) schematic! Thanks for letting me know to be dubious.

Comment: The "voltage flowing" is at the heart of your misunderstanding. Current flows. Voltage "is". If there is a difference in voltages (and only if) then current can flow through whatever resistance there might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the cap is discharged, you are in a situation similar to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4wYr7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since the cap is discharged, it is initially at zero volts.  So what is the voltage at pins 6 and 2?  Zero.

Of course, this starts changing as soon as current starts flowing into the cap.  At first, all the voltage is dropped over the resistors, but as the cap starts to fill up, its terminal voltage starts to rise from zero.  Now less and less current is flowing over the resistors, therefore less and less voltage is being dropped by them.  Eventually the voltage across the cap (and therefore on pins 2 and 6) is high enough to trigger the comparators.

Think of it this way:  The voltage can't get from the power rail to pin 2 or 6 without passing current through the resistors.  Ohm's law tells us that current through a resistance drops voltage.

Let's look at the case when the capacitor has just finished discharging:

[image: From https://electronicsclub.info/capacitance.htm]

[Image Source](https://electronicsclub.info/capacitance.htm)

Let us agree that when the capacitor is discharged, there is the same voltage on both its terminals.  Let us also agree that the voltage seen at pins 2 and 6 is the same as the 'top' of the capacitor.

Now the capacitor starts charging as current flows from the 5 V source, through the resistors, and into the capacitor.  Since this current is limited by the resistors, the rate at which the capacitor fills is called its RC time constant.  i.e. This voltage rise is defined by the size of the resistors and the capacitance.

As the capacitor fills up, the voltage on the upper terminal starts to rise from ground.  Remember, whatever voltage this terminal is at is the voltage that pins 2 and 6 are seeing.

Eventually this voltage is high enough to trigger the comparators, and the discharge pin gets grounded and discharges the capacitor, and now the whole thing starts over.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the schematic. This "no cap" version is helpful (I hadn't realized the importance of the "top" part of the circuit being a voltage divider)! I am confused about what exactly is going on once we introduce a capacitor however. If I'm understanding correctly the higher voltage on the capacitor will mean there is less potential from +5v at pin 2 (say 2v when the capacitor is up to 3v?). What exactly happens then? Going off of the comment about less voltage being dropped, is the claim that there are (5 - whatever is now being dropped over the resistors)v at pin 2?

Comment: Or, is it the case that the voltage of the capacitor is what I'm seeing across pin 2 (as "in current is flowing from the capacitor into the comparator")? Is this and the logic I mentioned in the comment above the same phenomenon at work?

Comment: @Lockjaw I made some edits that hopefully clear things up.  Let me know if I'm making sense, or need to explain further/differently.